# Webapi model binder not constructing a complex type?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have this api action :

```
[Route("~/api/products/{productCode}/price")]
public IHttpActionResult PutProductPrice(string productCode, 
PriceBindingModel binding) {
```

when I send a request to this endpoint with no request body like this :

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 0
```

In the body of the PutProductPrice binding is null. (different from MVC)

I'm used to Model Binder create a PriceBindingModel using it's default parameterless constructor and assigning the values (in this case there is none)

Is this supposed behavoir ? should I check if Model is null in all my api requests ?
I guess this is a bug or some other problem I'm not seeing.

**Note:** Sending {} (empty object) on the request, makes the BindingModel be created and getting the expected bad request with a failed modelstate. (which I supposed should happen in the first scenario (sending an empty body) as well.

**Note 2:** doing this in the first line on the controller make it work as expected:

```
binding = binding ?? new PriceBindingModel();
```

ideas ?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I believe it should be possible to override the model binder to "fix" this, but I would love to know if you figured out something more simple.

Comment: I simply added `if (binding == null) return BadRequest();`

Comment: Seems reasonable, as long as `PriceBindingModel` has one or more required properties. Guess I might have to override the model binder (or use the in-method fix) in my case where the model has no required properties. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode you can use an action filter like the one created by Ben Foster : https://github.com/benfoster/Fabrik.Common/blob/master/src/Fabrik.Common.Web/Filters/NullModelCheckAttribute.cs

Comment: I am not sure how this is relevant. What I want to do, is to have my action invoked with a `new MyModelClass()` as parameter rather than `null` when the request does not contain any of the models properties. In my particular case it is a GET request and the parameter is marked `[FromUri]` so it is slightly different from what you had, even though I believe the source of the `null` value is the same.

Comment: @JørnSchou-Rode OH, ok. If you want to create an instance when null is received then yes, that link is not relevant.